# Make Functor from a Lambda Function in C++

Tags: c++, c++11

Is it possible to create a functor from a lambda function in C++?

If not, why not?

It's giving me a surprising bit of trouble to do.

Practical Use Case:

Another function requires making a functor like so:

```
Class::OnCallBack::MakeFunctor(this, &thisclass::function);
```

Typically in order to use this, I have to make a function within `thisclass` which means adding to the header file.
After a lot of uses, there's a good bit of bloat.
I want to avoid this bloat by doing something like:

```
Class::OnCallBack::MakeFunctor(this, 
    void callback()
    { []() { dosomething; } });
```

What goes wrong is compilation errors for starters.
Even if it did compile, is it possible to do something like this?

Comment: A lambda *is* a functor (a class type with an overloaded `operator()`). Perhaps you could post an example of what exactly you're having trouble with.

Comment: To be explicit: please list a practical problem.  Describe what you tried to solve it (and a description why), and what went wrong.  Include a minimal example of your attempt to fix it, and include any error messages that happen.  Describe explicitly what you wanted to happen, but did not happen, as well as what happened that you did not want to happen.

Comment: Thought: Cablen, by "functor" are you saying "stateless function object"?

Comment: i've added clarification

Comment: What does the signature of `MakeFunctor` look like? If it's something like `MakeFunctor(T*, R(T::*)())`, then you don't have any option but to provide a pointer to member function along with a pointer to the object. Also, things would be a lot easier if you could post a [complete, compilable example](http://sscce.org) instead of providing tidbits every time someone asks you another question.

Comment: What's the signature of `Class::OnCallBack::MakeFunctor`?  And is it a template?  If it's a template, and expects a functor, you can probably pass it a lambda directly.  If it's not a template, and requires something derived from a base interface...  Lambda classes cannot derive from anything.

Comment: AndyT's solution works.  Sorry for the confusion and for this question in general.  The problem was a lot more specific to the code base I'm working with than I thought it was.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't specified a signature of `Class::OnCallBack::MakeFunctor` so I guess it's something like:

```
template<typename T>
Functor<T> MakeFunctor(T*, doesnt_matter (T::*)(doesnt_matter));
```

just because `this` is passed explicitly in your example.

In this case it's not a problem of C++ but of your `MakeFunctor`. If it would be:

```
template<typename F>
Functor<F> MakeFunctor(F f);
```

you could call it as:

```
Class::OnCallBack::MakeFunctor([]() { dosomething; });
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to store the lambda function you could do it like this for a `void()` function

```
std::function< void() > callback = [](){ dosomething };
```

Or, for a function with a return type and parameters,

```
std::function< int( int ) > callback = []( int i ){ return dosomething(i);}
```

You'll need to include this file to use `std::function` though.

```
#include <functional>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are no lambda functions in C++.  The "lambda" structure in C++ defines a class with an `operator()`.  A functor, in some.  It also defines an instance of that class.

I don't know what your actual problem is, but I would guess that it has something to do with the fact that you cannot name the type of the lambda.  You can usually work around this by using `decltype`, e.g.:

```
auto f = [](...) { ... };
typedef decltype( f ) LambdaType;
```

The other problem might be that every instance of a lambda, even identical instances, have different, unrelated types.  Again, the solution is probably to create a named variable with a single instance of the lambda, using `auto`.

Comment: Lambdas define a class.  Calling that a lambda class seems natural.  Such a lambda class has a member function operator().  Calling that member function a *lambda function* doesn't seem to far out in left field.  Finally, it requires a strange definition of instance to make "every instance of a lambda has a different type".  The same lambda expression produces the same type of lambda class, at least within the same translation unit, in my experience.  Does the standard disagree?